# DurationField format in a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django model that contains a duration field:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    duration = models.DurationField()
```

And I want to render a form for this model using a ModelForm:

```
class EditEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['duration']
```

Which is all working. However, if editing an existing model, the duration rendered in the text box is of the format `HH:MM:SS`

I will never be dealing with durations over an hour. How can I change how Django is formatting this field in the form to just be `MM:SS`?

I already have a custom template filter in use when rendering the model, I just can't figure out how to change how the form is rendered.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do this by providing a custom widget for the field:

```
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_duration

class DurationInput(TextInput):

    def _format_value(self, value):
        duration = parse_duration(value)

        seconds = duration.seconds

        minutes = seconds // 60
        seconds = seconds % 60

        minutes = minutes % 60

        return '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(minutes, seconds)
```

and then you specify this widget on the field:

```
class EditEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['duration']
        widgets = {
            'duration': DurationInput()
        }
```

Of course, this will cause weirdness if you do ever supply durations longer than an hour...

Comment: This looks on the right track, but unfortunately, `value` is a `str` object by the time it gets to the `_format_value` method. I guess I can parse the string, and reformat, but that is a bit uglier than having access to the actual duration

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise it was a string by then. If you want to access the actual value then you can perform the same logic inside the `prepare_value` value method of a subclassed `DurationField`?

Comment: I have edited the answer to something that should actually work - agree with you however that parsing the string isn't ideal.

Comment: I went with making a subclassed `DurationField` that overrides the `prepare_value` method, which works fine and gives you access to the `timedelta` object. However, I'm accepting your answer since it works and put me on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case i needed to remove the milliseconds so i did what MichaelM suggested by

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime

from django import forms

from harvests.models import Harvest


def duration_string(duration):
    # Removing the milliseconds of the duration field
    days = duration.days
    seconds = duration.seconds
    microseconds = duration.microseconds

    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds = seconds % 60

    hours = minutes // 60
    minutes = minutes % 60

    string = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)
    if days:
        string = '{} '.format(days) + string
    # if microseconds:
    #     string += '.{:06d}'.format(microseconds)

    return string


class CustomDurationField(forms.DurationField):
    def prepare_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, datetime.timedelta):
            return duration_string(value)
        return value


class HarvestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    work_time_interval = CustomDurationField()

    class Meta:
        model = Harvest
        fields = '__all__'
```