# How to force duration display as H:i in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a duration field which with validations, the maximum is 24 hours.
However, when 24 hours is displayed it shows as: `1 day, 0:00:00`

I want it to show as `24:00`

I am currently displaying the `DurationField` as follows:

```
<td>{{ entry.duration }}</td>
```

Comment: Hey, @surfer190 I was wondering, did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: John your answer was about the form field, I was looking to just display the duration in the template. So I went with a template tag.

Comment: Ok good to know!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom widget for your duration field to manipulate your output, as shown in this answer: [DurationField format in a ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33078366/durationfield-format-in-a-modelform?answertab=votes#tab-top).

```
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_duration

class DurationInput(TextInput):

    def _format_value(self, value):
        duration = parse_duration(value)
        days = duration.days
        seconds = duration.seconds

        minutes = seconds // 60
        seconds = seconds % 60

        hours = minutes // 60
        minutes = minutes % 60         

        return '{:02d}{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(
            hours if hours != 0 else 24, minutes, seconds
        )
```

Then use it in your form.